# Java servlet url path without appname

Tags: java, spring, servlets

I have a project running on Servlet 3.x, Spring & Jersey. Usually we specify URLs with a  pattern that includes the appname, like:

`http://localhost:/appname/testfunction?parameters=X`.

However, we would like to have the option of specifying a URL without the appname, like:

`http://localhost:/testfunction?parameters=X`.

I gather a web-fragment might help with this goal, but I don't exactly know how to implement this.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3):

The configuration depends on the Servlet container, but what you are referring to is known as the context path. You can set your web app's context path to the empty string or set it as the root web app.